# ActionLink con glyphicon y Button

Tags: asp.net

Quisera saber como puedo hacer para que esto`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IDPROJECT})` pueda darle formato, lo hice de esta manera pero no me funciona:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Proyectos")" class="btn btn-warning" >Editar
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </a>
```

este es el resultado que quiero

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera por medio del método [`ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", "Proyectos", new { Id = item.IDPROJECT },
    new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit" });
```

Donde el cuarto parámetro es un objeto de tipo `IDictionary<string, object>`, denominado `htmlAttributes`.

Comment: en caso de que solo quiera poner el puro icono como seria, porque no me funciona de esta manera `@Html.ActionLink("","Edit", "Proyectos", new { Id = item.IDPROJECT },new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit",@title="Editar" })`

Comment: En lugar de eso, ponle: `@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", "Proyectos", new { Id = item.IDPROJECT },
    new { @class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit" });`, si te das cuenta, el primer parámetro del `ActionLink` es el nombre y es requerido, pero si le pones un espacio puedes omitirlo ;)

Comment: Gracias, me funciono de esa manera.